# Bulk update with mapping in NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm creating an index with mappings the following way:

```
_elasticClient.Indices.Create(name, c => c.Map(/* omitted for brevity */));

_elasticClient.BulkAll(data, b => b
                .Index(name)
                .BackOffTime("30s")
                .BackOffRetries(2)
                .RefreshOnCompleted()
                .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                .Size(50)).Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), _ => { });

_elasticClient.Indices.PutAlias(name, Alias);
```

I'm just trying to understand how the bulk update works and make sure I do this correctly. Even if I remove `_elasticClient.Indices.Create`, an index still seems to be created. Does a POST to `index_v1/_bulk` create the index if it doesn't exist, but update it with data if I create it first with my first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if data is indexed into an index that does not yet exist, Elasticsearch will create the index and infer the mapping for documents based on the first document it sees. This *can* be useful, but typically for a search use case, you want to explicitly control the mapping for documents to apply specific analyzers, etc., so creating the index with the mapping you desire is the preferred approach.